# Trouble with having a subquery with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm having trouble trying to use a subquery with an INNER JOIN.

In the code below, the average rating I'm trying to compute needs to be only the **average rating of that player (a.player)**.

From looking at my script below, **my questions are**:

1) Where should I nest the subquery when using INNER JOIN?

2) There are about 20 names in the table I'm pulling this information from (table 'college'). In the subquery I need 'b.rating' to be for that specific player. Do I need a WHERE clause in the subquery, something like "WHERE player=a.player"?

```
$query = "SELECT a.player,a.team,a.loc,a.pic,a.rank,b.rating FROM college AS a
        JOIN (SELECT AVG(rating) AS rating FROM college_rating) AS b
        ON a.player=b.player
        ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 20";
$run = mysqli_query($link,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
echo $row['player'] . ' ' . $row['rating'] . ' ' . $row['team'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find average rating for each palyer in subquery as shown below

```
$query = "SELECT a.player,a.team,a.loc,a.pic,a.rank,b.rating FROM college AS a
          JOIN (
                SELECT player,AVG(rating) AS rating 
                FROM college_rating
                GROUP BY player
               ) AS b
        ON a.player=b.player
        ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Answer (score 0):

$query = "SELECT a.player,a.team,a.loc,a.pic,a.rank
, ( SELECT AVG(rating) FROM college_rating where player = a.player GROUP BY player ) as rating
FROM college a
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 20";